# Android device need to be on same network than meteor server (VM)

Tags: android, meteor, ionic-framework, virtual-machine, vmware

My android device and my meteor server need to be on the same network to communicate (Cf. Warning message). My meteor server is running on Ubuntu inside a VM with VMWare Workstation 12 Player, my android is connected to my local WiFi. How can I do it ?

```
$ meteor run android-device --port 3001

=> Started proxy.
WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile
app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device
is on the same network, and that the network configuration allows
clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
=> Started your app.                                            
=> App running at: http://localhost:3001/     
=> Started app on Android Device.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VMWare Menu, go to `Player > Manage > Virtual Machine Settings > Network Adapter` and select `Bridged`. Maybe you will need to restart your VM, me I didn't.

You can check that the two host are in the same network with `ifconfig -a` on Ubuntu and `ipconfig` if your physical machine is running Windows. If it is not working, try to ping from your physical machine other equipment connected to your local network (sometime provider appliance filter internal traffic).